# HTTP headers "Accept" and "Content-Type" in a REST context

Tags: rest, http-headers

I understand that the [`Accept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) HTTP header defines a data type expected in a *response* sent from the server, so it's used as a response header.

My question is regarding the [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type), it's used by a client to define the body format of a request sent. I always used it as part of a client request, so I have a client request where I set the headers with `Accept` and `Content-Type`. And recently, I came across a project where the `Content-Type` is defined in the response headers (so sent by the server).

So my question is: `Content-Type` need to be set as part of the client *request* header or as part of the server *response* header or can it be set to both?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

The difference can be found in the specifications, in this case [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231):

> [5.3.2.  Accept](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2)
>
> The "Accept" header field can be used by user agents to specify
> **response** media types that are acceptable.

---

> [3.1.1.5.  Content-Type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5)
>
> The "Content-Type" header field indicates the media type of the
> **associated representation**

The `Accept` header always indicates what kind of *response from the server* a client can accept. `Content-Type` is about the content of the current request or response, depending on which kind of HTTP message it is applied.

So if a request has no payload, you don't have to send a `Content-Type` request header, and the same goes for your response: no body — no header necessary.

Some servers may require you to provide a `Content-Type` in a request even if the request has no payload; the server should return a `415 Unsupported Media Type` response if you omit it.

Comment: Can the server decide if it wants a `content-type`? I use graphql and the server on localhost does not work without both `content-type` header and `accept`. Regarding content-type, servers should guess it according to the data structure sent.

Comment: @Timo why should the server guess? The client knows what it sends, so it should advertise it. Guessing leads to errors. There are multiple formats that look like JSON, but have different semantics.

Answer (score 57):

Accept header is used by HTTP clients to tell the server which type of content they expect/prefer as response. Content-type can be used both by clients and servers to identify the format of the data in their request (client) or response (server) and, therefore, help the other part interpret correctly the information.

Comment: I can read in https://www.soapui.org/testing-dojo/best-practices/understanding-rest-headers-and-parameters.html that content-type is used only for REQUESTS, using methods POST or PUT, so not in the response.. Are they wrong?

Comment: I wouldn't say they're wrong, it's only that they are not talking about responses (to be honest I haven't read the full article). SoapUI acts as an HTTP client and the text is written from that perspective. But, if they clearly say, Content-type header only applies to requests, then yes, they are wrong :)

Answer (score 21):

**TL;DR**

The entity header `Content-Type` is used to indicate the media type of the resource. In responses, a `Content-Type` header tells the client what the content type of the returned content actually is. In requests, such as POST or PUT, the client tells the server what type of data is actually sent.

**Elaborated Answer**

As you correctly note, the `Accept` header is used by HTTP clients to tell the server what response media types are acceptable. The server, on their turn, will then send back a response, which will include the `Content-Type` header telling the client what the media type is actually returned.

Now, the `Content-Type` header could be on request and responses as well. Why? Well, think about POST or PUT requests. With those request types, the client is actually sending a bunch of data to the server as part of the request, and the `Content-Type` header tells the server what the data actually is and thus determines how the server will parse it.

Answer (score 12):

MDN offers a clear explanation of this:

### [Accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept)

The Accept request HTTP header advertises which content types, expressed as MIME types, the client is able to understand. Using content negotiation, the server then selects one of the proposals, uses it and informs the client of its choice with the Content-Type response header. Browsers set adequate values for this header depending on the context where the request is done: when fetching a CSS stylesheet a different value is set for the request than when fetching an image, video or a script.

### [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)

The Content-Type representation header is used to indicate the original media type of the resource (prior to any content encoding applied for sending).

In responses, a Content-Type header tells the client what the content type of the returned content actually is. Browsers will do MIME sniffing in some cases and will not necessarily follow the value of this header; to prevent this behavior, the header X-Content-Type-Options can be set to nosniff.

In requests, (such as POST or PUT), the client tells the server what type of data is actually sent.

Answer (score 8):

**Content negotiation:**  is the mechanism that is used for serving different representations of a resource at the same URI.

The *Accept* is Client **Request-header** field can be used to specify certain media types which are acceptable for the response.

The *Content-Type* is **entity-header** field indicates the media type of the entity-body sent to the recipient.

HTTP header fields provide required information about the request or response, or about the object sent in the message body. There are four types of HTTP message headers:

- **General-header:** These header fields have general applicability for
  both request and response messages.
- Client **Request-header:** These header fields have applicability only
  for request messages.
- Server **Response-header:** These header fields have applicability only
  for response messages.
- **Entity-header:** These header fields define meta information about the
  entity-body or, if no body is present, about the resource identified
  by the request.
  [Source](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_header_fields.htm)

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html
https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Object_Headers.html