# ASP.NET Web API 2 routing json or xml format

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Tyring to apply formatting on json and xml at once in a web service:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApiWithExtension2",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}.{ext}",
                defaults: null,
                constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) }
            );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiWithExtension1",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}.{ext}",
            defaults: null,
            constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) });

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.AddUriPathExtensionMapping("xml", "application/xml");
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.AddUriPathExtensionMapping("json", "application/json");
```

But I'm keep getting 400 error, when I'm trying to get response with extension (and without it). None of the routes works:

api/person.xml

api/person

api/person/1.json

api/person/1

If I'm using only "DefaultApi" route - everithing is ok (with no extensions I'm getting json).
What am I'm missing?

Comment: WebApi can return wide range of formats if setup correctly, and you can define you desired type by sending it in the header. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722586/header-parameters-accept-and-content-type-in-a-rest-context) question.

Comment: Agreed, I'm using YARC to test it, and send proper payload to the service, but it doesn't rote to the Get method

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?

Comment: This looks correct.  I've gone over your code with a fine-tooth comb and can't spot the error.