# How to capture Json from web site using c#

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I have a paid subscription to Seeking Alpha and have a cookkie which enables me to get full data from `https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/AAPL/financials-data?period_type=quarterly&statement_type=income-statement&order_type=latest_left&is_pro=True`

I'd like to collect JSON response using C#

Below is my horrible code

```
        string cookie = "my super secret cookie string";


        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
        request.AddHeader("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0");
        request.AddHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        string url = "https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/AAPL/financials-data?period_type=quarterly&statement_type=income-statement&order_type=latest_left&is_pro=True";

                    request.AddParameter("cookie", cookie, ParameterType.Cookie);

        var client = new RestClient(url);

        var queryResult = client.Execute(request);

        Console.WriteLine(queryResult.Content);
```

How can I get it to return JSON to me? I am getting something but not the JSON I want

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jebgbn Here is a `fiddle` with exact same code as you post in `question`. You can check it returns `json`. Strangely if you try few time it will start returning `html` in some of the response. Then again its returning `json`.

Comment: Yes. I think I need to authenticate somehow. I have a cookie string, just need to pass it somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After poking around for a bit I figured it out. For the benefit of all:

```
    private bool FinancialStatement(string symbol, string statement, string period)
    {
        var target = $"{BASE_URL}{symbol}/financials-data?period_type={period}&statement_type={statement}&order_type=latest_left&is_pro=True";

        var client = new RestClient(target);

        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Cookie", MACHINE_COOKIE);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        dynamic responseObj;
        try
        {
            responseObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return response.IsSuccessful;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your `Access` header to `application/json`.

```
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

> `Accept` indicates what kind of *response from the server* the client can accept.

You can get more info for `Accept` from [Header parameters: “Accept” and “Content-type” in a REST context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722586/header-parameters-accept-and-content-type-in-a-rest-context)

Comment: Good idea, but this is not it. I think I am setting cookig incorrectly. Should it be `request.AddParameter("cookie", cooki1, ParameterType.Cookie);` or `request.AddCookie("machine_cookie", cooki1)`?

Comment: Ok. `Accept = application/json` will required when `server` returning data as multiple formats and default format is not `json`. As per your comment it seems that you're not having issue with `Accept`.

Comment: I changed it to application/json. Response is empty