# React Response with 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, rest, post

I am new to React and I try to do a POST fetch to an API.
I however get the response 415 Unsupported Media Type.

This is the output of my program in browser inspector:
[image]

and the following is my code:

```
fetch(url,
{
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(object)
}).then(...)
```

I have tried every possible accept en content-type, but I keep getting a 415.
What am I doing wrong, I searched the internet but did not found a solution.

Comment: The response has an `Accept: application/vnd.cars+json`.

Comment: Do I need to add it in accept or in content type?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35722727/2442804 - for now you can try both.

Comment: What is that type, do I need to reformulate my body?

Comment: Probably not - some backend engineer felt like they wanted to have a more descriptive type than just "json" in the header.