# Symfony-Giving all api responses according to content type

Tags: php, symfony

routes.yaml
[image: routes.yaml]

Whatever the content type is, I want the response to be of that type. How can I do it?

I want it to be response, by content type. I want to do it globally. For example; If the content type is json, the response must be json. If the content type is XML, the response should return XML. or if the content type is xxx the response should return xxx

The system itself should automatically determine the return type according to the content-type. Is this possible in symfony? Because Symfony returns exceptions in xml format by default. If the api user sends the content-type as json and receives an exception, it receives it as xml. I dont want this.

I can write _format json or xml. But I want it to be dynamic

Comment: Should the response type match the type from the request? Or from the configuration? In both cases: why not read that data and act accordingly in your code?

Comment: To be clear, you don't want to support every possible content type header, right? You probably only want to support XML and JSON I'm guessing?

Comment: I want the response exactly according to the content-type. @ChrisHaas

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, share your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: What is not fully understood in my question. @NicoHaase  I want it to be response, by content type. I want to do it globally. For example; If the content type is json, the response must be json. If the content type is XML, the response should return XML. or if the content type is xxx the response should return xxx

Comment: That's a clear requirement. But what have you tried to fulfill it? How does your controller look like? You either need to write some code to achieve that, or use any external library like ApiPlatform

Comment: Wow, every possible content type is a big ask unto itself. CSV, EBCDIC, RTF, etc., I'm not sure how to even build such a thing. I'm saying that tongue-and-cheek because you probably want to constrain your results to a known list, not "whatever is provided by the client". Also, it might be worth honoring the [`Accept`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35722727/231316) header, if provided, too.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community -Chris Hass -Nico Haase The system itself should automatically determine the return type according to the content-type. Is this possible in symfony? Because Symfony returns exceptions in xml format by default. If the api user sends the content-type as json and receives an exception, it receives it as xml. I dont want this..It should work globally. I don't want to specifically check in a code block

Comment: I guess no one knows how to fix this. I condemn Symfony. Because Laravel provides this automatically. It automatically sets the return type according to the content type.

Comment: Why not inspect how Laravel does this? Their code is open to read for everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check how [HttpKernel](https://github.com/symfony/http-kernel/blob/6.2/HttpKernel.php#L135) is handling response.

---

To have response type dynamically respond to client sent `Accept` header you must write some kind of mapper for it.

You should write some subscriber/listener to transform your response to needed format:

```php
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

final class ResponseSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function __contstruct(private Request $request) {}

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::RESPONSE => 'onResponse',
        ];
    }

    public function onResponse(ResponseEvent $event): void
    {
        // Skip on internal requests. E.g. redirect
        if (!$event->isMainRequest()) {
            return;
        }

        $data = $event->getResponse();

        $requestedType = $this->request->headers->has('Accept')
            ? $this->request->headers->get('Accept')
            : 'application/json';

        $response = match ($requestedType) {
             'application/json' => $this->getJsonResponse($data),
             'application/xml' => $this->getXmlResponse($data),
             'text/html' => $this->getHtmlResponse($data),
             ...
             default => throw new \InternalException('Request type ' . $requestedType . ' is not supported'), // This better be checked on KernelEvents::REQUEST
        }

        $event->stopPropagation();
        $response->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

---

You can use XDebug to do step-debugging and see where your response data is travelling for better understanding of Symfony internals.

Comment: is this a global solution. I don't think there is a global solution. I don't think it will work in Symfony system exceptions.

Comment: Exceptions thrown by the system will continue to arrive in XML format.  Even if there is no global solution , this code may work in the responses under our control . but in the system's own errors, the content-type will not return the incoming type.

Comment: @AkifTezcan Ok, I understood your requirements. Check updated answer with response event handling

Comment: Do we need to define the Response Subscriber class somewhere? Do I have to point somewhere?

Comment: @AkifTezcan This is [simple subscriber](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-subscriber) with ordinary process. You can change `$this->request` to `$event->getRequest()`